# How to get the real owner of a CalendarListEntry in Google Calendar API to distinguish between owned and shared calendars?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

The `CalendarList` entries returned by Google Calendar API v3 contain a `accessRole` property. However, the `owner` value in this property simply represents the owner "role" in terms of ACL, which in Google's web interface maps to the role "Make changes and mange sharing" when sharing a calendar.

But clearly there is a true, account owner for each calendar. This owner cannot be modified by other shared "owners", and this is the only kind of property that would allow us to distinguish between a truly "owned" calendar vs. a calendar shared by others but granted "owner" role, when accessing a user's `CalendarList`.

Google's own web GUI shows this value under calendar settings. It can be seen in both the true owner and shared owner's account.

But I cannot find a way to obtain this value via API. Without it, I cannot retrieve only self-owned calendars of a user, which is what I'm trying to do in my app.

Any idea if this is possible at all, or just a limitation of Google API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the point of view of Google Calendar API any user that

> can read and modify events and access control lists

is a `calendar owner`.

This is different from the `calendar creator`.

Currently there is not API endpoint to retrieve the latter, but you can file a feature request for it on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).